# Does a typed dataset use reflection at runtime?

Tags: ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

Does a typed dataset use reflection on runtime?

Comment: Is this an ADO.NET related question? Not sure how this could be language agnostic, as implementation would surely differ between frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is just a code generated wrapper that completely compiled and does no reflection in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A typed dataset normally consists of and XML Schema and a corresponding class file in your project language.

On of the main draws of typed datasets is that the class makes the schema information available at design and compile time, allowing your code to catch invalid casts and data inputs prior to runtime.  There is no reason for reflection to be in use on a typed dataset since you have the object definition in your project namespace.